# Should perform a click operation to load an alert using selenium webdriver.Details are provided in the body for the steps

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

Scenario is we have to login to this website:http://way2automation.com and then move to the alerts page and then click the button in simple alert.There is no id nothing for this button.Only a simple Java script function.How can we handle this?

```
package sampletest;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.JavascriptExecutor;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.interactions.Actions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;

public class alertspractice {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","F:\\drivers for browsers\\chrome driver\\chromedriver.exe");
          ChromeDriver driver=new ChromeDriver();
        driver.get("http://way2automation.com/way2auto_jquery/index.php");
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        WebElement name=driver.findElement(By.name("name"));
        name.sendKeys("jayath");
        WebElement Phone =driver.findElement(By.name("phone"));
        Phone.sendKeys("8790141375");;

        WebElement email=driver.findElement(By.name("email"));
        email.sendKeys("a@yopmail.com");
        WebElement city =driver.findElement(By.name("city"));
        city.sendKeys("visakhapatnam");
        WebDriverWait wait=new WebDriverWait(driver,40);
        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.xpath(".//[@id='load_form']/fieldset[6]/input")));
        WebElement username =driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='load_form']/fieldset[6]/input"));
        username.sendKeys("jayath1234");
        WebElement password =driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='load_form']/fieldset[7]/input"));
        password.sendKeys("jayath234");


        WebElement submit1 =driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='load_form']/div/div[2]/input"));
        submit1.submit();


        WebDriverWait wait2=new WebDriverWait(driver,40);
        wait2.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.linkText("Alert")));
        WebElement alert123=driver.findElement(By.linkText("Alert"));
        alert123.click();
        wait2.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//html/body/button")));
        WebElement getalert=driver.findElement(By.xpath("//html/body/button"));
        JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
        js.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", element);




    }

}
```

Comment: Code is needed that you have tried.  Also this sounds like a student trying to get someone else to do their homework for them.  I really hope this isn't the case.  We are here to help, but not here to do your work.

Comment: @IamBatman I did not get the solution to the above problem.Moreover have told u the scenario as well.If u think that u are doing my work kindly don't answer.I am expecting an answer from people who can answer me as i have already tried this and that is the reason why i told that there is no id for that button.

Comment: Then show what you have already tried.  Just pointing at a website that requires a MEMBER login and saying move to "alerts page" then click simple alert is not how you ask someone to help you.  So if you would actually read HOW TO POST A QUESTION in stackoverflow and give us more information then maybe we'd be more prompt to help you.  So instead of being rude about it, you need follow the standard here at stackoverflow or find somewhere else to get help.

Comment: That is a free website @IamBatman.I have edited my question and posted it to you.It is not a member login it is a free website to practice automation.Kindly post your dummy details and register.I was explaining the navigation for the same as you are saying that its not the way to ask a question.Kindly understand and reply me.I am waiting for an answer.

Comment: Please read [ask], especially the part about [mcve] (MCVE), and [How much research effort is expected?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) This will help you debug your own programs and solve problems for yourself. If you do this and are still stuck you can come back and post your MCVE, what you tried, and the execution result including any error messages so we can better help you. Also provide a link to the page and/or the relevant HTML.

Answer (score 0):

Finally after digging, had to get the direct link in your code you were talking about to get to the alerts section.  There seems there are two buttons on that page, one which is hidden behind a tab, the input alert.  I'm going to assume it's the first button, but it wouldn't be hard to change it for the input alert as well.

```
//button[contains(text(), 'Click the button to display an alert box:')]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
WebDriverWait wait2=new WebDriverWait(driver,40);
wait2.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//button[contains(text(), 'Click the button to display an alert box:')]")));
WebElement alert123=driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[contains(text(), 'Click the button to display an alert box:')]"));
alert123.click();
```